# Making onclick work with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, onclick

I am trying to make a simple script for class. I have figured out how to do the onclick event and array separately but am not sure how to make them work together. I still want the fortunes to change on refresh but have the option to click the button.

Onclick:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get your fortune!</button>
<p id="fortune"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = ???? ;
}
</script>
```

Array:

```
<script>
var fortune = new Array(10);
fortune[0]="May life throw you a pleasant curve.";
fortune[1]="Procrastination is the thief of time.";
fortune[2]="Your road to glory will be rocky, but fulfilling.";
fortune[3]="Patience is your alley at the moment. Don’t worry!";
fortune[4]="All things are difficult before they are easy.";
fortune[5]="If you want the rainbow, you have to tolerate the rain.";
fortune[6]="Determination is what you need now.";
fortune[7]="Do not let ambitions overshadow small success.";
fortune[8]="First think of what you want to do; then do what you have to do.";
fortune[9]="Hard words break no bones, fine words butter no parsnips."; 

c=Math.round(Math.random()*9);

document.write(fortune[c]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Also add the event listener via `addEventListener` function.

```js
var fortunes = new Array(10);
fortunes[0]="May life throw you a pleasant curve.";
fortunes[1]="Procrastination is the thief of time.";
fortunes[2]="Your road to glory will be rocky, but fulfilling.";
fortunes[3]="Patience is your alley at the moment. Don’t worry!";
fortunes[4]="All things are difficult before they are easy.";
fortunes[5]="If you want the rainbow, you have to tolerate the rain.";
fortunes[6]="Determination is what you need now.";
fortunes[7]="Do not let ambitions overshadow small success.";
fortunes[8]="First think of what you want to do; then do what you have to do.";
fortunes[9]="Hard words break no bones, fine words butter no parsnips."; 

var fortune = document.getElementById("fortune");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   var c = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
   fortune.innerHTML = fortunes[c];
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Get your fortune!</button>
<p id="fortune"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
var fortune = new Array(10);
fortune[0]="May life throw you a pleasant curve.";
fortune[1]="Procrastination is the thief of time.";
fortune[2]="Your road to glory will be rocky, but fulfilling.";
fortune[3]="Patience is your alley at the moment. Don’t worry!";
fortune[4]="All things are difficult before they are easy.";
fortune[5]="If you want the rainbow, you have to tolerate the rain.";
fortune[6]="Determination is what you need now.";
fortune[7]="Do not let ambitions overshadow small success.";
fortune[8]="First think of what you want to do; then do what you have to do.";
fortune[9]="Hard words break no bones, fine words butter no parsnips."; 

function myFunction() {
  c = Math.round(Math.random()*9);
  //document.write(fortune[c]);
  document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = fortune[c] ;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get your fortune!</button>
<p id="fortune"></p>
```